# Using AngularJS grag $first item in ng-repeat and use it to open items information in other form on page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My users will land on my contacts page where a list of all contacts are listed at the top of the page in an ng-repeat and then contact info can be added and edited. The list is populated with an edit button to grab individual contacts for editing.

My newest requirement is to grab the first contact in the list and populate the information in the forms for editing as if the user clicked on the first edit button. I imagine using $first in some way in the ng-repeat but how to fire this first contact edit on landing is a reach for me.

I have read that the $scope hash is internally looped and dirty checked against former values each time a digestion occurs.  Have tried using init and it was not read; probably my lack of understanding of the physiology of Angular.

I am hoping to do this all in the UI but in case this is misguided I included the api call in the bottom of this entry.

```
table class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>First Name</th>
                                <th>Last Name</th>
                                <th>Title</th>
                                <th>Active</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="scacContact in searchScacContactResults">
                                <td>{{scacContact.contactFirstName}}</td>
                                <td>{{scacContact.contactLastName}}</td>
                                <td>{{scacContact.contactTitle}}</td>
                                <td>{{scacContact.activeDescription}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="onEditScacContact(scacContact)" ng-disabled="isAdding||isEditing">Edit</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

<fieldset>
        <legend>Add/Edit Contact</legend>
            <form class="form-inline" role="form" name="AddEditContact">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="form-group" 
                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">First Name</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                            <input class="form-control" id="ContactFirstName" name="ContactFirstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name" ng-disabled="!isAdding&&!isEditing" ng-model="scacContactDetails.contactFirstName" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" 
                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" >Last Name</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                            <input class="form-control" id="ContactLastName" name="ContactLastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" ng-disabled="!isAdding&&!isEditing" ng-model="scacContactDetails.contactLastName" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Active?</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed fixed-element">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Yes</th>
                                        <th>No</th>
                                    </tr>

                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <input name="rbActive" type="radio" ng-disabled="!isAdding&&!isEditing" ng-value="true" ng-model="scacContactDetails.active">
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input name="rbActive" type="radio" ng-disabled="!isAdding&&!isEditing" ng-value="false" ng-model="scacContactDetails.active">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </form>
    </fieldset>

//Getting list of Contacts per ScacID
var scacContactListRes = $resource("api/SearchScacContact");
scacContactListRes.query({ scacID: $scope.scacID }, function (scacContactList) {
    $scope.searchScacContactResults = scacContactList;

});
```

Comment: The thing with $first is, that every item in an ngRepeat gets it's own scope, so you'd have to assign the first element to the parent scopes property. This is kind of less elegant. @sherwaniusman has it right, otherwise you could also assign the first item in your controller after the query has succeeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @sherwaniusman for the lead, pointing the first item in the array to the model. I tried every method of getting the UI to call the method in my ctlr to no success.  Might be a UI-Router thing but I eventually just called the onEditScacContact() in my ctlr; inside of the query where I populate the viewmodel for contacts.

```
 //Getting list of Contacts per ScacID
        var scacContactListRes = $resource("api/SearchScacContact");
        scacContactListRes.query({ scacID: $scope.scacID }, function (scacContactList) {
            $scope.searchScacContactResults = scacContactList;
            // This populates the page with the editable content of the first content in the list
            $scope.onEditScacContact($scope.searchScacContactResults[0]);
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

One work around would be this

`<form class="form-inline" role="form" name="AddEditContact" ng-init="scacContactDetails = searchScacContactResults[0]>`

Comment: Thanks @sherwaniusman, this is definitely a start. Gonna work on an ng-if to fire the onEditScacContact button.

Comment: ng-if on ng-repeat is for filtering out results in the list. It will be called on all items in the list. You can call a function in it and check if its the first entry, assign it to from model.

Comment: Have been calling ng-click="onEditScacContact(scacContact)" from pretty much everywhere. Inside ng-repeat with init, inside <tr> <td> and inside your form. Have not gotten it to fire my method.